# Cache transform reuse

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to reuse a shared lookup cache?

I've used the Cache transform component into a foreach loop to inizialize a lookup with a parametrized query.

The cache must be rewritten for every iteration of the loop.

But on the second iteration I receive the error:

```
Error: 0xC0010200 at fill lookup cache, Cache Lookup Events [1]: The component "Cache Lookup Events" (1) cannot write to the cache because component "Cache Lookup Events" (1) has already written to it.
Error: 0xC0010201 at fill lookup cache, Cache Lookup Events [1]: Failed to prepare the cache for new data.
Error: 0xC004701A at fill lookup cache, SSIS.Pipeline: component "Cache Lookup Events" (1) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0010201.
```

One idea was to limit the cache lifetime to the loop scope. Like for variables. But I don't know how to assign a scope to the cache.

How can I clean and rewrite a cache or delete and recreate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried to find an answer to this myself but apparently the all connections are open through out the whole time the package is running..

You might be able to get around this by creating a child packages that populates a file cache as child packages don not share connection managers..

Answer (score 2):

My reading on cache's suggest that **within one package execution**, a particular cache can only be loaded once. Refer to this article "[SSIS cache transform  – Failed to Prepare the Cache For New Data](https://lsdbtech.wordpress.com/2016/11/11/ssis-cache-transform-failed-to-prepare-the-cache-for-new-data/)".

There may be a solution to your question that you can pull out from [this blog](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2008/05/06/ssis-2008-incrementally-updating-the-lookup-cache-file/). But it would be using a filesystem task to rename the cache.

A further option is to script the cache connection manager and create it dynamically as in this [blog](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26409529/SSIS-Script-Cache-Connection-Manager.html).